# What is the MQL4 code to create an object like rectangle on main chart?

Tags: mql4

There is no point beating around the bush. Sincerely, am still learning coding in MQL4. My problem is that I want to have an MQL4 template that displays rectangle on chart. I want to add some code for it to display specific color, depending on price dynamics.

Answer (score 1):

Use Metatrader Editor, there you type a code ( alike this below ) and may use both the context-help, shown as you type and also the installed MQL4-Documentation, to read all further details and debug the target application use.

```
ObjectCreate( windowID,
              anObjectNAME,
              OBJ_RECTANGLE,
              subWindowID,
              aTime1,
              aPrice1,
              aTime2,
              aPrice2
              );

ObjectSet(    windowID,
              anObjectNAME,
              OBJPROP_COLOR,
              clrAsYouWouldLikeToHAVE
              );
```

Comment: upvote as the author has not enough rating to reward you for all your answers :)